# node.js aws-sdk access S3 dir with space in name

Tags: aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am trying to access object in S3 which has space in in dir name `assets/storage/media/Hybrid LED Bulb/replace-icon.png`

But when I try to access it this in my node.js code it uses this path `assets/storage/media/Hybrid%20LED%20Bulb/replace-icon.png`

I tried to wrap this with `encodeURI()` but this one makes it `assets/storage/media/Hybrid%2520LED%2520Bulb/replace-icon.mobile.png`

Whats is the correct way to handle this in node.js ?

Answer (score 0):

I know in some situations, a space is replaced by a `+`. Try replacing the space before handing over the S3 key/path parameter to your function. I haven't tested this, but thought it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

`decodeURI(uri)` helped to solved my issue.